# JCR Node Throw An Error No matching definition found

Tags: aem

I am trying to create languages node under /etc . But its giving me an error
`No matching definition found for child node languages with effective type [nt:unstructured]`

Did anyone faced that issue and know the fix? I want to display selective languages, related with my dictionary,  when i select my dictionary under `http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/i18n/translator.html` . Now I see all the default languages.

Comment: How did you try to create them? Did you follow the ISO convention?

Comment: The error indicates that its not allowed to create a new node of type nt:unstructured under the node where you are trying to create it. Can you elaborate on the issue?